# How to test the result of a curried function in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jasmine, cycle

Use Case:

- I have a module of functions, each function is unit tested
- I have a factory function that creates a stream of these functions that  a third party library requires.
- I would like to test that this factory function produces the correct stream. Using `@cycle/Time`, I am able to create the stream and assert on the stream.
- I am able to assert that the functions appear on the stream in the correct order.
- However, I am unable to assert on any function that is curried. How would one assert on curried functions?
- Currently, I have a hack in place to `JSON.stringify` the functions and assert on their source.

To simplify the problem, I created a simple test suite so we aren't concerned with using `@cycle/Time`. It appears that curried functions are new instances of the function. Please see the code below.

I was wondering how would I be able to make the failing test pass? In this case I simulate the curried function by using `bind`. Is this possible?

```
const a = () => b
const b = () => {}
const c = (arg) => b.bind(null, arg)
const d = () => () => {}

describe("curried function test", function() {

  it('should return a reference to b', () => {
    expect(a()).toBe(b)
  })

  // This test fails because b.bind returns a new function.
  it('should return a reference to a curried b', () => {
    expect(c('foo')).toBe(b)
  })

  it('should create a new instance everytime', () => {
    expect(d()).not.toBe(d())
  })

});
```

I've setup a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/22oyt2w5/1/).

Comment: Test the *behaviour* - what do you expect the result to *do*?

Comment: Unfortunately, the functions exist inside a stream, but I guess I could map the functions with test data... but it seems indirect.

Comment: _"This test fails because b.bind returns a new function."_ > yea, that's because what you get is the result from `bind`, which isn't the same as `b`. Otherwise, `b.bind` would be _modifying_ `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"This test fails because `b.bind` returns a new function."*

That's because what you get from `c` is the result from `b.bind(null, arg)`, which isn't the same as `b`.
Otherwise, `b.bind` would be *modifying* `b`.

As mdn says:

> The `bind()` method creates **a new function** that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.
>   <sub>([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), emphasis mine)</sub>

Basically, `c` *can't* return a reference to `b`.

What you *do* have, is the resulting function's name:

```js
const b = () => {};
const c = (arg) => b.bind(null, arg);

const e = c("foo");

console.log(e.name);
console.log(e.name === `bound ${b.name}`);
```

So, you could test that `e.name` equals `"bound " + b.name`.

Comment: This looks promising... since I have unit tests for the individual functions already, I guess I really only care that the appropriate function appears on the stream by name in the expected order. Elegant solution.

Comment: @Pete: Just be cautious, I don't know how different browsers work in this regard. I'm not sure how standardized this is.